# fopen opens File before calling it

Tags: c, file, fopen, autoit, createprocess

First my code:

```
void RecvPaths(char *szRETURN)
{
    FILE *hFILE;
    char *szFILE = new char[2048];
    hFILE = fopen("FLM.tmp", "r");

    do
    {
        fgets(szFILE, 2048, hFILE);
        strcat(szRETURN, szFILE);
    } while(!feof(hFILE));

    fclose(hFILE);
    return;
}
```

And now my Problem:
I start my Program which contains this function. It creates a new process with `CreateProcess`. The program called this way should write some data to "FLM.tmp". When it has finished, I call this function to read the data, written by the other program. But it's always nothing. I also opened the file with the Windows explorer and there's also nothing. So I checked the other program and this works definitely. Next I tried to change the Path of `fopen`in this function and let the path in the other Program stay the same and NOW it writes his data in "FLM.tmp". Its like that my prog opens this file before starting the new process and that it's blocking it. But I never opened this File in another part of my prog. Has anyone an idea what could solve this?

Edit: Ok, some of you wanted the code of the second program. Here it is. (It's written in AutoIt):

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Local $aFilelist, $sFilelist, $i, $hFile

$hFile = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & "\FLM.tmp", 2)


If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then
    $aFilelist = DriveGetDrive("ALL")
Else
    For $i = 2 To $CmdLine[0]
        $CmdLine[1] = $CmdLine[1] & " " & $CmdLine[$i]
    Next

    $aFilelist = _FileListToArray($CmdLine)
EndIf

_ArrayDelete($aFilelist, 0)
$sFilelist = _ArrayToString($aFilelist, @CRLF)
FileWrite($hFile, $sFilelist)
FileClose($hFile)
Exit
```

And again, when I start it by myself without the first program, it WORKS.

---

I'm a bit confused, but now it works. Maybe it was a problem with my system, I don't know. But thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Has szRETURN been zeroed before you call this function? Otherwise strcat will be looking to append to an uninitialised string and the results would obviously be undefined.

Comment: Where's the code that spawns the other process, AND waits for it to finish ? (also, Your RecvPaths never deletes szFILE , so it leaks memory.)

Comment: You'd better use a `while(!feof(hFILE)) { ... }` construct to read from a file, as you could get an `1 == feof()` immediately after opening it.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a relative path to fopen(), so it may be opening a file in another folder you are not expecting, as the calling process's working directory can change dynamically. Always use absolute paths when opening files.

Comment: No. My problem isn't that it doesn't read it into my prog. My problem is, that when I call the second prog from my prog then the second one doesn't write anything into the file. If I run it from the explorer, the second program works perfect. And if I change the path in fopen to a new file, the second prog writes it into the old file perfectly.

Comment: So are you sure your second program, which might be an idea to post here, is not opening a file in a different folder? Have you done a search on your hard drive for all files named FLM.tmp? When you open without a path, the working folder may be different as the answer indicates. What is the timestamp on the file after calling your second program? Has it changed?

Comment: @Shadowigor perhaps there's an error in the code that waits for your program to finish - and you end up calling RecvPaths before that program is finished.

Comment: No, that I checked too. That's not the problem.

Comment: Go to http://www.sysinternals.com and download the FileMon utility. It allows you to watch file I/O activity in real-time, so you can see exactly what both apps are doing, which paths they are accessing, how much data is being written to and read from which files, etc.

Comment: Nice tools. They didn't solve my problem, but I'm sure they can help me at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

some comments:

(1) you have a mem leak - you never delete szFILE.

(2) you should specify a max size as an additional argument to the function so that there is no accidental memory overwrite

```
RecvPaths( char* szRETURN, size_t maxLength )
```

(3) there is no need to have an empty `return;` at the end of the function since method is declared returning void.

(4) you should verify that the other program/process closes the file properly, if the file is still open it may cause your problem since the file contents may not have been flushed to the disk.

(5) In windows the recommended way to handle file IO is to use the Windows specific methods e.g. [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can handle things like windows file permissions and give you a more descriptive error message if some error occurs.

Comment: OK. 1 to 3 I understand. About 4: Yes it's closing it. But at 5: I don't really understand these functions. Could you give me an example?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx